# New characteristic function from old

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

The question I want to do says:

Let $f(u,t) : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function, such that for each $u$, $f(u, \cdot)$ is a characteristic function, and such that for each $t$, $f(\cdot, t)$ is continuous. Show that

$$F(t):=  \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u,t) dG(u) $$

is again a characteristic function for any distribution function $G$.

My attempt is as follows. I'm not sure if it is correct, as I don't use the continuity of $f$; my argument appears to only require measurability.

Let $(X_u)_{u \in \mathbb{R}}$ be a family of random variables such that the characteristic function of $X_u$ is $f(u, \cdot)$ for each $u \in \mathbb{R}$. Define a new random variable $Y$ by its law:

$$P(Y \in A) := \int_{\mathbb{R}} P(X_u \in A) G(du) $$

for Borel $A$. Putting this differently, for Borel $A$ we have

$$E(\textbf{1}_A(Y)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} E(\textbf{1}_A(X_u)) G(du) $$

and by a monotone class argument this equation readily extends for bounded measurable functions.

In particular, writing for fixed real $t$, $g_t(x):= \exp(itx)$ we obtain

$$E(\exp(itY)) =E(g_t(Y)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} E(g_t(X_u)) G(du) =  \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u,t) G(du). $$

This shows that $F$ is the c.f. of $Y$.

My questions are: 1. Is this argument correct? 2. If so, why do I not require continuity, but just measurability?

Many thanks for your help.

PS I am not keen on applying Bochner's theorem, as this, though completely correct and technically easy in this case, does not motivate the origin of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

I think sometimes ch.f is better to be associated with measure $\mu$ or distributions instead of random variables (sometimes, of course random variable would be better).

Here, consider function $G(x,u)$, such that for fixed $u$, $H(\cdot, u)$ is the distribution function corresponding to the characteristic function $f(\cdot,\cdot)$. By the uniform continuity of $f(\cdot, \cdot)$, we can actually show for fixed $x$ $H(x,u)$ measurable in $u$. Thus by theorem 4 in *Robbins et al.
(1948)*, we know the following function defined by integral would be a distribution $$F(x)=\int_u H(x,u)dG(u)$$

The realised rv with respect to the distribution $F$ would have ch.f of the form $\int f(u,t)d G(u)$.

Answer (score 0):

The $X_u$ should **not** be independent: if they were, I think that $X_Z$ would not be measurable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have outlined a different approach which may bypass some technical concerns. What do you think of it? Thanks again.